# Instrumented test with spinner and arrayAdapter

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, testing

I have searched for awhile solutions on the Internet and the forum, but I couldn't find any solution to my problem. And I am stuck with this for awhile.

I am trying to test that when I call a method (**showLanguage (String language)**) then the language displayed is the right one.

This method is inside a class (**OnePrinterSettingFragment**), and it calls two methods on a spinner and an ArrayAdapter set on the the spinner. (I have removed many things inside the class **OneprinterSettingFragment**, but basically, what I think is worth to consider is that the method **showLanguage** calls **getPosition** on an **ArrayAdapter**, and **setSelection** on a **Spinner**)

```
public class OnePrinterSettingFragment extends BaseFragment implements View.OnClickListener, OnePrinterSettingFragmentContract.View {

      protected Spinner spnLanguagePrint;

      private ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> languageAdapter=ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(PosApplication.getInstance().getApplicationContext(),
       R.array.language_printing_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);

     @Override
      public void showLanguage(String language){
      int pos = languageAdapter.getPosition(language);
      spnLanguagePrint.setSelection(pos);
      }
}
```

And here is the test :

```
RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
```

@PrepareForTest(OnePrinterSettingFragment.class)
public class OnePrinterSettingFragmentInstrumentUnitTest {

```
OnePrinterSettingFragment mView;
Context mContext;

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {

    mContext = InstrumentationRegistry.getContext();

    mView = new OnePrinterSettingFragment();

    mView.setSpnLanguagePrint(new Spinner(mContext));
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> languageList = new ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>(mContext,R.array.language_printing_array);

    mView.setLanguageAdapter(languageList);
    mView.setSpnLanguagePrint(new Spinner(mContext));
    mView.getSpnLanguagePrint().setAdapter(languageList);

}

@Test
public void showLanguage() throws Exception {

    mView.showLanguage("Vietnamese");
    assertTrue("Failed to show Vietnamese language", mView.getSpnLanguagePrint().getSelectedItem().toString()=="Vietnamese");
}
```

}

I didn't mock the class **OnePrinterSettingFragment** because when I do it, android studio throws an **abstractError**, and when I do like it is above, android studio says that **mView.getSpnLanguagePrint().getSelectedItem()** is **null**

I am blocked, and I have tried to understand why it is null, but I don't get it. I thought that in the **setup** method of the test, declaring the views (spinner and so on) is enough. But apparently no.

If anyone can help me please.

Thanks in advance